# Solving quadratic equation using PHP, array problem

Tags: php, arrays, equation

I'm receiving the $data that says "Your equation is: axˆ2+bx+c=0" where a, b and c are different every time (random algorithm). For exemple my equation is: 2xˆ2+6x+3=0  I have extracted the numbers from the $data with preg_match_all and I have got array for it, so:

```
[0] = 2
    [1] = 6
    [2] = 3
    [3] = 0.
```

Logically I need to say after that `[0] = 'a', [1] = 'b'`, etc and start the calculating of roots with D
But, when my other random equation is `xˆ2 + 5x + 10 = 0`

```
My array is [0] = 5 [1] = 10 [2] = 0
```

And with the logic above `[0] is not further = 'a'` How to be in such situation? I'm lost.

Comment: "_How to be in such situation?_" Hard to tell without actually seeing any of your code

Comment: Hard to tell with such a short fragment, but it looks like if you're expecting 4 arguments and only receive 3, you can conclude that the first argument (for your `x` coefficient) is missing and should be assumed to be 1. If you're using a regex to pattern-match,  you'll have to remember that a missing number for a coefficient would mean 1, as in "1x^2". You'll need a more sophisticated regex that can also match null values, like `(\d*)x\^2` for a possibly-missing argument in an x^2 expression. If it's missing, treat it as 1.